# Passing a checkbox value from a Flask-WTForms form in a redirect back to the same form

Tags: flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

Using Flask and Flask-WTF, I want to re-direct to a page with a form that has a checkbox.
I have an initial search-page that has a form called "SearchForm", and after a user searches, I redirect him to a results-page that has the same SearchForm on it, followed by a listview of results. This enables the user to search again on the results-page.

This is my form:

```
class SearchForm(Form):
    """Search form class"""
    from app.utils.translation import Translation

    criteria = StringField(Translation.label('search'), validators=[DataRequired()])
    all_employees = BooleanField(Translation.label('all_employees'), validators=[])
```

Now when the users submits the form, I can instantiate it like so:

```
form = SearchForm(request.form)
```

And I can get to the data using (for example):

```
form.data['all_employees']
```

If I don't check the checkbox, WTForms correctly parses all_employees as *False*.
I redirect to the results-page that has the same form on it, and I would like to render that form with the data that the user just submitted. So I do this:

```
return redirect(url_for('employees.search',
                        criteria=form.data["criteria"],
                        all_employees=form.data["all_employees"]
                        ))
```

On the searchform, I instantiate the form again, with the querystring (URL) variables:

```
form = SearchForm(request.args)
```

Now the problem is that because form.data['all_employees'] *has a value* "False", the checkbox is checked. This is ofcourse normal behaviour for HTML, a checkbox value is only passed if the box was checked. So if there is a value (and "False" **is** a value), the checkbox gets checked.

I could work around this using something like this in my redirect:

```
all_employees='y' if form.data['all_employees'] else ''
```

But that means that I'd have to constantly do that for every checkbox field in every redirect. I have a lot of similar screens that I'd like to implement this way.

I can imagine that WTforms could also in some way parse "falsy" values for a checkbox, and not check the box in those cases, but I can't find any documentation if this is even possible.

I also considered handling it on the result-page, and removing a variable from the request.args collection if the value is "falsy", but that feels kludgy as well.

Maybe there is another way of doing this, that I'm not aware of, or maybe my workaround is just the way to handle redirects with a checkbox, I don't know, but it seems to me that this is a pretty common use-case that Flask-WTForms would probably have some sort of solution for.

Any advice would be appreciated.

**EDIT**:

The problem is even bigger; I just noticed that passing an empty string to my redirect, using this code:

```
all_employees='y' if form.data['all_employees'] else ''
```

And subsequently instantiating and rendering the form using:

```
form = SearchForm(request.args)
```

Will render empty checkboxes as:

```
<input id="include_inactive" name="include_inactive" type="checkbox" value="">
```

Therefore, checking it again afterwards, will pass an empty string back to Flask, so when a checkbox is unchecked once, it will have an empty value rendering after that, and it can never be checked again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very basic, the urlencoded string `otherdata=value&all_employees=False` is a truthy value from the perspective of HTML checkboxes.

WTForms *mostly* follows the rules of HTML forms and form data. However, since this boolean value thing is a common pet peeve,  you **can** customize this using the [false_values](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/2.1/wtforms/fields/core.py#L696) keyword parameter to define 'falsey' values... you could make `false_values` include the string `False`.

The alternate way, to be more 'HTML spec friendly' would be a helper something like this:

```
def url_for_form(urlname, form, **kwargs):
    for field in form:
        if field.data:  # would exclude blank strings too
            kwargs[field.name] = field.data

    return url_for(urlname, **kwargs)
```

usage would be like `url_for_form('blah.search', form, otherparam=9)`

If you need to pick specific fields out, then you could design it slightly differently.

Comment: I have actually tried the "false_values" parameter, but then WTForms renders my checkboxes with a default value of "False" instead of "y" for some reason. This messes things up, because then a checked box will pass "False", so I abandoned that approach. Your helper however, is a nice and clean workaround for this problem. I think I can work with that.